# Dnsmasq DHCP поверх PPP

Tags: dhcp, ppp, dnsmasq

Сейчас конфигурация такая

```
interface=l2tp*
interface=pptp*
except-interface=lo
except-interface=ens*
bind-dynamic

#dhcp-option=121,192.168.0.0/16,0.0.0.0 

dhcp-range=192.168.0.1,192.168.255.254,12h

dhcp-option=121,192.168.0.0/16
dhcp-option=249,192.168.0.0/16
```

С клиента прилетает запрос

```
20:43:09.628889 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 8454, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 328)
    192.168.94.36.bootpc > 255.255.255.255.bootps: [udp sum ok] BOOTP/DHCP, Request, length 300, htype 8, hlen 0, xid 0x7617f03b, Flags [none] (0x0000)
      Client-IP 192.168.94.36
      Vendor-rfc1048 Extensions
        Magic Cookie 0x63825363
        DHCP-Message Option 53, length 1: Inform
        Client-ID Option 61, length 17: "M-BM-^\M-h^TwsM-j^QM-^HM-:M-^SM-^@M-3BM-^UM-C"
        Vendor-Class Option 60, length 6: "ndhcpc"
        Hostname Option 12, length 5: "gate1"
        Parameter-Request Option 55, length 6: 
          Subnet-Mask, Domain-Name-Server, Domain-Name, Vendor-Option
          Netbios-Name-Server, Classless-Static-Route-Microsoft
        END Option 255, length 0
        PAD Option 0, length 0, occurs 14
```

А днсмаск говорит

```
dnsmasq-dhcp: no address range available for DHCP request via pptp-10
```

Нужно ответить просто с опциями 121,249. Адрес клиенту присвоен по ppp. Делал такое на isc-dhcp-server, но интересно как повторить на dnsmasq потому как он сервер dhcp на роутере.

В ответе конфигурация передаёт `Subnet-Mask Option 1, length 4: 255.255.0.0` но не передает 121 или 249

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dhcp-option=249,192.168.0.0/16` - тут не хватает `next-hop`.

Answer (score 0):

Вот с такой конфигурацией заработало, но не всё

```
except-interface=lo
except-interface=ens*
bind-dynamic

dhcp-range=192.168.0.1,192.168.255.254,255.255.0.0,12h
dhcp-option=tag:vpn,121,192.168.0.0/16
dhcp-option=tag:vpn,249,192.168.0.0/16
```

Лог

```
22:22:39.127482 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 128, id 31359, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 328)
    192.168.94.35.bootpc > 255.255.255.255.bootps: [udp sum ok] BOOTP/DHCP, Request, length 300, htype 8, hlen 0, xid 0x68e63f38, secs 1536, Flags [none] (0x0000)
      Client-IP 192.168.94.35
      Vendor-rfc1048 Extensions
        Magic Cookie 0x63825363
        DHCP-Message Option 53, length 1: Inform
        Client-ID Option 61, length 17: "M-LM-PQM-G^]M-^^ZMM-^J^_^DvO#M-YM-`"
        Hostname Option 12, length 15: "DESKTOP-HP0BBE0"
        Vendor-Class Option 60, length 8: "MSFT 5.0"
        Parameter-Request Option 55, length 6: 
          Domain-Name-Server, Netbios-Name-Server, Vendor-Option, Subnet-Mask
          Classless-Static-Route-Microsoft, Domain-Name
        END Option 255, length 0
        PAD Option 0, length 0, occurs 2
dnsmasq-dhcp: no address range available for DHCP request via pptp-14
dnsmasq-dhcp: DHCPINFORM(pptp-14) 192.168.94.35 00:cc:d0:51:c7:1d:de:1a:4d:8a:1f:04:76:4f:23:d9:e0 
dnsmasq-dhcp: DHCPACK(pptp-14) 192.168.94.35 00:cc:d0:51:c7:1d:de:1a:4d:8a:1f:04:76:4f:23:d9:e0 DESKTOP-HP0BBE0
22:22:39.128704 IP (tos 0xc0, ttl 64, id 17997, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 328)
    192.168.94.1.bootps > 192.168.94.35.bootpc: [udp sum ok] BOOTP/DHCP, Reply, length 300, htype 8, hlen 0, xid 0x68e63f38, secs 1536, Flags [none] (0x0000)
      Client-IP 192.168.94.35
      Server-IP 192.168.94.1
      Vendor-rfc1048 Extensions
        Magic Cookie 0x63825363
        DHCP-Message Option 53, length 1: ACK
        Server-ID Option 54, length 4: 192.168.94.1
        Subnet-Mask Option 1, length 4: 255.255.0.0
        BR Option 28, length 4: 192.168.255.255
        Domain-Name-Server Option 6, length 4: 192.168.94.1
        END Option 255, length 0
        PAD Option 0, length 0, occurs 32
dnsmasq: query[A] client.wns.windows.com from 192.168.94.35
dnsmasq: query[A] tile-service.weather.microsoft.com from 192.168.94.35
```